# Devices sharing Apple IDs: what credentials can an user with an iPad PIN use?

Tags: ios, security, apple-id

I have several devices sharing the same Apple ID, one being an iPad (plus 2 iPhones, 2 Macs etc). I want to share my iPad PIN unlock code with others in my flat so they can use Spotify / control the Audio etc., but I don't want them to have access to anything else (e.g. my Apple account, my non-Apple email accounts).

Firstly, I don't believe there is any way (e.g. multiuser) way of me (e.g.) having my mail on there, and it not being available to anyone with the unlock code - correct?

Secondly, even if I delete my mail accounts, to what extent am I still in danger? Are secrets (e.g. passwords) shared between devices for Apps / Accounts? IE can people put them back without entering the password or restore the device to a state where it had the password? Can I stop the casual user deciding to buy lots of Apps? Is there a way to lock down the device less hammer-to-crack-a-nut than removing my Apple ID and all accounts or (e.g.) factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

You have some limited control by enabling a couple toggles.

1. Require password for all purchases, every time or use family sharing to restrict the ability of that iPad to get new downloads from the managed / signed in account of your choice. - https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/
2. Sign out of all and any cloud services you don’t trust them to not delete things (they can delete anything you can delete - photos, contacts, mails) so them reading the information is not the worst that can happen.

You might be able to use parental restrictions / guided access to lock one app in the foreground, but I would just say - have them get a used device or you get a used device and just let it be community / no accounts / require password to purchase or make a “children” account for the shared device and enroll AppleID in family settings so you have to explicitly approve all purchases on that secondary ID.

- https://support.apple.com/HT202612